# React's setProps() deprecated warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In parent component **App** I render child component **PersonsTable**:

```
  var App = React.createClass({
    addPerson: function() {
      // building personToAdd object and passing to personsTable...
      this.refs.personsTable.setState({personToAdd: person});
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <PersonsTable ref="personsTable" />
          ...
        </div>
      );
    },
  });
```

Now I'm passing a new object by calling **setState** method of PersonsTable.
If I call **setProps** method, it returns a warning

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: setProps(...): You called `setProps` on a component with a parent. This is an anti-pattern since props will get reactively updated when rendered. Instead, change the owner's `render` method to pass the correct value as props to the component where it is created.

How do I correctly pass such an object to PersonsTable without using **setState** method?

Here is full code https://jsfiddle.net/jpt5uy1k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to implement an anti-pattern by calling setState on a ref. It's better to pass props to the child and use those. If you need state, set it in a parent and pass it down as a prop.

```
    <div>
      <PersonsTable aProp={someCoolInfoOrParentState} />
      ...
    </div>
```

Refs should be used only when you need to "reach out" and get hold of an actual DOM node for one reason or another. Also, you generally want state in as few places as possible, since it can be complicated and requires extra "machinery" to make work. Better to keep state in a single place and thread it down through other components.

See this from https://github.com/reactjs/react-basic:

> We tend to prefer our data model to be immutable. We thread functions through that can update state as a single atom at the top.